# How to draw Thai/Chinese strings in J2ME?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, fonts, midp, cjk

I'm trying to draw Thai/Chinese strings on a J2ME `Canvas` using `graphics.drawString(string, i, i, aAnchor);` but the device **hangs** when I do so. When I use SOP on `string`, it displays `?????????`. I've tried hard-coding the string too as - `String string = "บริการโทรกลับ";` I've [read here](http://www.j2meforums.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=29f3663e1638f6942fa29da68cca7070&action=printpage;topic=12503.0) that the device also needs Chinese/Thai fonts installed on device, so I tested a Thai website on my device and found that it was able to display Thai characters in clickable links (text). I'm sure I'm missing something but just can't figure out what it is! Somebody, please point me in the right direction...

Blackberry related solutions are also welcome.

**EDIT** I've made a custom font [as described here](http://mobilefonts.sourceforge.net/) but was still unable to display it. Also, I could use some Thai/Chinese font files (preferably .fnt extension).

Comment: I was working same kind of project, you can rather use image for this purpose, as I dont think J2ME Allows Thai fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with [custom fonts with Java ME application?](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_custom_fonts_in_Java_ME) Also look on some useful search for [using custom fonts.](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=+site%3adeveloper.nokia.com+custom+fonts+++j2me&sa=X&ei=ravxTqOYJonNrQffvOz7Dw&ved=0CCcQrQIwAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=7ed7621b162bc8c&biw=1280&bih=678)

Comment: Yup...I'm trying the approach in the link I've provided (using custom fonts) but I need a thai font file...

Comment: Have you search on google? I found this [unicode format.](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/thai.html)

Comment: Have you actually achieved this functionality? Drawing English fonts is one thing my friend, this is another!

Comment: No. I didn't achieve this before. Have you seen that search results?

Comment: Finally, I've achieved this using a designer's help! I've added all the steps I've taken in your answer. Thanks...Graham Hughes's post helped a lot